# Wie wird das e in „Genus“ ausgesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-length, vowel

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Genus) bietet zwei unterschiedliche Aussprachen für den Vokal im Wort „Genus“:

- /ˈɡɛnʊs/ (wie „Bett“)
- /ˈɡeːnʊs/ (wie „Meer“)

Bei [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=genus) und [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&search=genus) werden die Hörbeispiele nur mit /ɛ/ ausgesprochen. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Genus#block_4) hat aber beide Aussprachen.

Haben die Aussprachen unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, oder ist der Unterschied dialektal? Wo sagt man was?

Comment: Ich höre da bei beiden eher ein /eː/ oder /eˑ/ heraus.

Comment: Ich spreche /'genus/

Comment: Ich spreche es wie in „*geh*en“ aus, kenne aber auch die Aussprache wie in „*Gä*nse“.

Answer (score 6):

*Genus* ist ein lateinisches Fremdwort, das nicht an das Deutsche angepasst, sondern aus der Quellsprache unverändert übernommen wurde. Da es mehrere verschiedene Aussprachemodelle für das Lateinische gibt ([Schulaussprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulaussprache_des_Lateinischen), [Deutsche Aussprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Aussprache_des_Lateinischen), [wissenschaftliche Aussprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinische_Aussprache)), hat sich wohl nie eine einzige Ausspracheform durchgesetzt. Es sind daher beide in der Frage genannten Varianten üblich, die sich in ihrer Bedeutung nicht unterscheiden. Eine regionale Vorliebe für eine der Aussprachen ist mir nicht bekannt.

Übrigens gehört *Genus* **nicht** der lateinischen u-Deklination an, weswegen das Wort auch nicht auf der letzten Silbe betont wird. (Man könnte dann fälschlicherweise annehmen, es handele sich um den Genitiv von *lat. genū* - Knie.) Dies zumindest dürfte allgemein anerkannt sein.

Answer (score 5):

Ich spreche das *e* in Genus wie das erste in *gehen* aus – als lange Silbe also. Ich habe allerdings auch die erste Variante gehört, in der das *e* wie in *Jenny* ausgesprochen wird. Ich vermute sogar, dass sie allgemein und v. a. im akademischen Umfeld häufiger verwendet wird.

Die Bedeutung bleibt in jedem Fall dieselbe; das heißt, dass es sich nicht um Homonyme handelt.

Ganz etwas anderes ist natürlich das Wort *Genuss*, das auf der letzten Silbe kurz betont wird.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Genuss"